# SonarQube - Elasticsearch could not bind

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

Last week SonarQube loaded in, worked nice and dandy. Now it throws this warning in `sonar.log`:

```
2017.03.16 11:58:47 WARN   es[o.e.bootstrap]  JNA not found. native methods will be disabled.
2017.03.16 11:58:47 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1489661925446] initialized
2017.03.16 11:58:47 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1489661925446] starting ...
```

Did not start of course. What could have changed while I was away?

Edit:
I did not provide the logs after trying to stop Sonar

```
Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2017.03.16 16:54:43 INFO  app[o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /proj/tn/tools/sonar/temp
2017.03.16 16:54:43 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[es]: /afs/sunrise.ericsson.se/se/app/vbuild/SLED11-x86_64/jdk/1.8.0_102/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/proj/tn/tools/sonar/temp -javaagent:/afs/sunrise.ericsson.se/se/app/vbuild/SLED11-x86_64/jdk/1.8.0_102/jre/lib/management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer /proj/tn/tools/sonar/temp/sq-process8365491608077217541properties
2017.03.16 16:54:43 INFO   es[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting es
2017.03.16 16:54:43 INFO   es[o.s.s.EsSettings]  Elasticsearch listening on 127.0.0.1:9001
2017.03.16 16:54:43 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1489679683034] version[1.7.5], pid[438787], build[00f95f4/2016-02-02T09:55:30Z]
2017.03.16 16:54:43 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1489679683034] initializing ...
2017.03.16 16:54:43 INFO   es[o.e.plugins]  [sonar-1489679683034] loaded [], sites []
2017.03.16 16:54:43 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.env]  [sonar-1489679683034] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/proj/tn (seroisproj02002.mo.sw.ericsson.se:/uproj020036/tn)]], net usable_space [330.8gb], net total_space [4.4tb], types [nfs]
2017.03.16 16:54:44 WARN   es[o.e.bootstrap]  JNA not found. native methods will be disabled.
2017.03.16 16:54:45 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1489679683034] initialized
2017.03.16 16:54:45 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1489679683034] starting ...
2017.03.16 16:54:45 WARN   es[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Fail to start es
org.elasticsearch.transport.BindTransportException: Failed to bind to [9001]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.bindServerBootstrap(NettyTransport.java:422) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.doStart(NettyTransport.java:283) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:85) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.doStart(TransportService.java:153) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.start(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:85) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalNode.start(InternalNode.java:257) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.search.SearchServer.start(SearchServer.java:46) [sonar-search-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:102) ~[sonar-process-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.search.SearchServer.main(SearchServer.java:81) [sonar-search-5.6.2.jar:na]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /127.0.0.1:9001
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:272) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport$1.onPortNumber(NettyTransport.java:413) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.transport.PortsRange.iterate(PortsRange.java:58) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.bindServerBootstrap(NettyTransport.java:409) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss$RegisterTask.run(NioServerBoss.java:193) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.processTaskQueue(AbstractNioSelector.java:391) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:315) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss.run(NioServerBoss.java:42) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42) ~[elasticsearch-1.7.5.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
2017.03.16 16:54:45 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1489679683034] stopping ...
2017.03.16 16:54:45 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1489679683034] stopped
2017.03.16 16:54:45 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1489679683034] closing ...
2017.03.16 16:54:45 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1489679683034] closed
```

Server OS: Linux

Comment: To be clear, you're seeing this in `sonar.log`? And if so, what platform?

Comment: Yes, this is from `sonar.log`
I'm using a remote linux server.

Comment: Why "Did not start of course"? I don't see any errors nor shutdown in these logs. Moreover could you mention version of SonarQube?

Comment: Well it was not an error message, but thought this is the cause. Still, nothing happens, sonar does not start. If I shut it down, I get the message: Sonar was not running.
By the way, I use the LTS version: SonarQube 5.6.6

Comment: You should probably provide the full logs.

Comment: Sure, my bad. Edited the post included the logs after a 'stop sonar' attempt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved, bit ashamed, but as the log said the port 9001 was used by someone else on the server (probably my own previous process) so elasticsearch could not bind.

Simply changed it to 9002.